# How to declare and Use Generic Map in this case

Tags: java, generics

I have different classes of map keys

```
class MapKeyParent{}

class MapKeyOne<U> extends MapKeyParent{}

class MapKeyOne<U,V> extends MapKeyParent{}
```

I have a class where there is an array of maps which can hold these keys,

```
class MapStorage{
    Map<MapKeyParent, Integer>[] mapArray;

    public MapStorage() {
    super();
    mapArray= 
        new HashMap<MapKeyParent, Integer>[NO_OF_RANKS];

    mapArray[0] = new HashMap<MapKeyParent, Integer>();
    mapArray[1] = new HashMap<MapKeyParent, Integer>();
    ....
    }

    public void addToMap(int index, MapKeyParent key, Integer value )
    {
       mapArray[index].put(key, value);
    }

    public Integer getFromMap(int index, MapKeyParent key)
    {
       return mapArray[index].get(key);
    }
}
```

How to apply Generics to MapStorage for MapKeyParent while declaring, putting and getting?

Comment: I think you might be asking about sticking objects in different a map according to their type? If that's the case try a Guava ClassToInstanceMap that itself contains maps.

Comment: By the way, stuff like that gets really complicated really quickly in java because of type erasure, so you might want to think really hard about what you're trying to do and find a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays cannot have a component type that is a parameterized type.  At runtime the parameterized type would lose the generic type information due to type erasure. This would allow any object implementing the `Map` interface to be added to the array.

You can work around this by using a `List` and specifying its type argument as `Map<MapKeyParent, Integer>`.

```
List<Map<MapKeyParent, Integer>> mapList;
```

See the [Generic Faq](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Can%20I%20create%20an%20array%20whose%20component%20type%20is%20a%20concrete%20instantiation%20of%20a%20parameterized%20type?) for a more detailed explanation.

This would require you to refactor your code:

```
class MapStorage{
    List<Map<MapKeyParent, Integer>> mapList;

    public MapStorage() {
       mapList.add(new HashMap<MapKeyParent, Integer>());
       mapList.add(new HashMap<MapKeyParent, Integer>());
    ....
    }

    public void addToMap(int index, MapKeyParent key, Integer value )
    {
       mapList.get(index).put(key, value);
    }

    public Integer getFromMap(int index, MapKeyParent key)
    {
       return mapList.get(index).get(key);
    }
}
```